# __doPostBack() is causing post back but not calling button click event in aspx page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using a aspx page which is having a button.

```
 <asp:Button ID="savebtn" runat="server" OnClick="savebtn_Click" Style="display: none" />
```

There are two ways to cause post back as shown in the below code.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
               var id = document.getElementById('<%= savebtn.ClientID %>');
       //Cause post back & calls page load but not savebtn_Click event
            __doPostBack('<%= savebtn.ClientID  %>', 'OnClick');

    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
                     var id = document.getElementById('<%= savebtn.ClientID %>');
           //Cuase postback & calls both PageLoad and savebtn_Click events.
           //If I use method, There is no way to know which control caused postback
            id.click();

    });
```

When I use __doPostBack, It calls page load event but not btn click event.

**Is there any way using __doPostBack to trigger Page Load as well as savebtn_Click event.**

If I use id.click(); as shown above, I am able to call savebtn_Click but it does not tells me which control caused the post back.

Comment: why are you trying to do postback using clientside?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

have you tried using the **UniqueID** instead of the **ClientID**?

```
__doPostBack('<%= savebtn.UniqueID %>', "");
```

Also have a look at this [quick tutorial](http://aspalliance.com/895_Understanding_the_JavaScript___doPostBack_Function) on dopostback:

Comment: This worked but it would be great if anyone can explain how it works.

Comment: UniqueID returns the value from the name attribute (using $ as the separator) and ClientID returns the value from the id attribute (which uses _ as the separator).  

An explanation of how it works:

"UniqueID also plays major role in postbacks. The UniqueID property of a server control, which supports postbacks, provides data for the __EVENTTARGET hidden field. The ASP.NET Runtime then uses the __EVENTTARGET field to find the control which triggered the postback and then calls its RaisePostBackEvent method."

https://www.telerik.com/blogs/the-difference-between-id-clientid-and-uniqueid

Answer (score 2):

I solved this question using this code:

```
  document.all('Button1').click();
```