# JQuery/ASP.NET Frustration

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, modal-dialog

I am pulling my hair out trying to figure out why this code doesn't work!
I have a GridView control on an ASP.NET page, and that grid contains a link for editing each record as an ItemItemplate field.  When clicked, a JQuery script executes to open a modal form for editing the record, and that works fine.  I can add new records and edit existing ones.
The issue comes when I click the modal form's 'Close' button, which should trigger a refresh of the GridView to reflect the changes made.  This is accomplished by having an ASP:Button that calls a DataBind event on the GridView.
The 'Close' event on the modal form fires, and I added a line to show the ClientID of the button to fire the event for, which works as it should.  But the GridView DataBind never fires.  I put a breakpoint on the btton's click event, but it never gets there.  Any ideas?  Here's the JQuery/JavaScript code I'm using in the form containing the GridView:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.popup').live('click', function (e) {

        var page = $(this).attr("href")

        var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
        .html('<iframe style="border:0px; " src = "' + page + '" width=600px" height="100%"></iframe>')
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            appendTo:"form",
            height: 550,
            width: 'auto',
            title: "Message Details",
            buttons: {
                "Close": function () { $dialog.dialog('close'); }
            },
            close: function (event, ui) {
                alert('<%=btnRefresh.ClientID %>');
                __doPostPack('<%= btnRefresh.ClientID %>', '');
            }
        });
        $dialog.dialog('open');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

I've read a number of posts on something similar, but I can't seem to implement the right fix.  The last thing I tried was adding the 'appendTo:"Form"' part suggested by someone in another post, but it doesn't change anything for me.
The btnRefresh code works fine.  I just can't figure out how to make it fire when the user clicks the close button on the modal form.

Comment: You can try `UniqueID` instead of `ClientID`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394931/dopostback-is-causing-post-pack-but-not-calling-button-click-event-in-aspx-p.

Comment: I tried that just now (thanks for the suggestion) and it gives me a different ID on the alert, but still no joy in getting the event itself to fire.

Comment: Here is another one, 100% not tested: `setTimeout(function () { __doPostPack('<%= btnRefresh.UniqueID %>', ''); }, 100);`. If it works, you can try with 0 instead of 100.

Comment: Nope, nothing with that either, although I DO appreciate the suggestions!  This is driving me NUTS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be `__doPostBack` instead of `__doPostPack`.

You may also need to change `ClientID` to `UniqueID` as mentioned in the comments. The `UniqueID` also should be the `name` attribute of the button. something looking like this maybe: `ctl00$btnRefresh`.

Comment: You know, some days I shouldn't be allowed to sit at the keyboard!!!! I don't know HOW in the world I missed that, but you're right!  It works, and thank you!  I guess I'm curious why IntelliSense didn't catch it or I didn't get a scripting error.  Maybe that's why I overlooked it.

Comment: If it's possible to feel any more stupid than I do at this moment, could someone please share it?  (VERY red-faced right now!)

Comment: lol it happens to us all... its a right of passage kind of thing ;)

Comment: Rite of passage?  They're going to tear up my union card and kick me out of the programming community for doing stupid things like that and then BROADCASTING my stupidity on the largest developer help site out there!! (grin)  I really appreciate your help with this, by the way.

Comment: @DanielAnderson - If it can make you feel better: you were not the only one who missed it. And I have already gone through that rite of passage in the past (and will certainly go through it again in the future).

Comment: I appreciate you being so helpful,Connors fan! Things like that can make a person seriously ponder a change of careers, you know?

Comment: @DanielAnderson The only reason I knew to look for that error was because it had kicked my ass in the past (typos in general). Sometimes you learn more from your mistakes than your triumphs, like a scarred warrior lol. The rest of your code and approach is fine - continue on